# MVC4 ckeditor file upload unable to return url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor4.x

I have implemented CKeditor file browse and upload in my mvc4 application. File browse is working fine but when I click on file browse it will not show the image in preview box.

[enter After file browse it will display the URL in textbox not preview pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za3Cp.jpg)

[It should display like this after click on browser image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUaAT.jpg)

Below JS code is used to set URL on textbox.

```
function updateValue(id, value) {
            // this gets called from the popup window and updates the field with a new value 
            $('#' + id).val(value);
        }
```

Another thing is when I choose file and send it to server, where is the path gone.

Here is my code of controller.

```
public void uploadnow(HttpPostedFileWrapper upload)
        {
            if (upload != null)
            {
                string ImageName = upload.FileName;
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/content/images/uploads"), ImageName);
                upload.SaveAs(path);
            }

        }
```

Just let me know how to fix these 2 things. using ckeditor mvc4 from nuget package

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
            filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/home/uploadPartial',
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/home/uploadnow',            
        });
```

Comment: Take a look at this example  http://amitraya.blogspot.com/2014/09/ck-editor-implement-your-own-image.html

Comment: thanks but I solved it. I already did the same steps from that link.